# Python Regular Expression Multiple Overlap Grouping

Tags: python, regex, grouping, overlap

```
a = 'foo<99>bar'
match = re.findall(r'(<\d(\d)>)',a)

## match gives [('<99>', '9')] but I would to have ['<99','9>']
```

I tried to escape the '(' but, the regex engine takes it a literal '('

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need grouping if you want that your output be `['<99','9>']` you can use pip:

`r'<\d+|\d+>'` .

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern

```
(?=(<\d+>))|(?=(\d>))
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qK3wI3/2)